# Drawing routes in Android collapses the device

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm developing an Android aplication that has to show some "places of interest" on a mapview, along with the device current location. This works well. 
Also, in my app, the user could "tap" a "place of interest" marker and the aplication would have to draw a route to that marker.

I used Google Directions api to get the route, along with a polyline decoder to get the GeoPoints between the user and the place. For my testing route, google gives me about 200 different GeoPoints.

So, I have a class like this to add those GeoPoints:

```
public class RouteOverlay extends Overlay {
    private GeoPoint gp1;
    private GeoPoint gp2;
    private int color;

    public RouteOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2, int color) {
        this.gp1 = gp1;
        this.gp2 = gp2;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
        paint.setColor(color);
        Point point2 = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setAlpha(120);
        canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x, point2.y, paint);
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }

}
```

what I do to draw the route is the following:
1) Detect the onClick event to a marker in the map.
2) From that event, I create a new thread, where I make the call to the Google API.
3) Once I have the result, I parse/convert it in a GeoPoint list.
4) Then I call my drawPath method:

```
private void drawPath(List<GeoPoint> geoPoints, int color) {    
    mapOverlays.clear();
    mapOverlays.add(myLocationOverlay);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    for (int i = 1; i < geoPoints.size(); i++) {            
    mapOverlays.add(new RouteOverlay(geoPoints.get(i - 1), geoPoints.get(i), color));
    }
    mapView.postInvalidate();
```

5) Finally, I return to the UI thread.

This method clears the map overlay list (mapOverlays). Then, adds to the list the current location and the "places of interest" overlays. And, finally, adds the route overlays.

The problem is that, suddenly, works veeery slow and finally crashes. But there is no message in the LogCat. So, I thought that 30 overlays + 1 + more than 200 for the route are too much for the phone to handle. But the tutorials I've seen do it this way so...

Can someone tell me if I do anything wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

When I called the drawPath function, after obtaining the List of GeoPoints, I made a loop to check the coordinates of each point. Something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < geoList.size(); i++){
    Log.i("GEOPOINT " + i, geoList.get(i).toString());
    drawpath(geoList, Color.BLUE);
}
```

The drawPath function got called N times. So the device crashed. My fault. 
Programming at 2:00 am is not good for the code!